# The /bin/ prefix to kill command is getting rid of the error message

Tags: debian, command-line, kill, error-handling

I have Debian Stretch..

I thought that a regular user could kill root process as root. I was using the command `/bin/kill 10733` as the user. There wasn't any error message.
Then, I typed out the similar command (without `/bin/` prefix) and the error message got displayed.

Here, is the command history

```
deployer@deployer:~/blog$ kill 10733
-bash: kill: (10733) - Operation not permitted
deployer@deployer:~/blog$ /bin/kill 10733
deployer@deployer:~/blog$ ps aux|grep 10733
root     10733  0.0  0.6  92360  6404 ?        Ss   19:19   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
deployer 10891  0.0  0.2  12732  2236 pts/0    S+   20:10   0:00 grep 10733
deployer@deployer:~/blog$ sudo kill 10733
deployer@deployer:~/blog$ ps aux|grep 10733
deployer 10900  0.0  0.2  12732  2232 pts/0    S+   20:10   0:00 grep 10733
deployer@deployer:~/blog$
```

In fact, I would prefer both the prefix and the message. How to get it? And why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the `kill` command is a shell internal (definitely in `bash`) and it allows for extensions such as `%1` to be used to refer to background processes.

On the other hand, `/bin/kill` is an external command and doesn't have these extensions.  Since it's a different program it acts differently.  A failed `/bin/kill` may be silent, but sets `$?` (exit code) to indicate a failure.

When you run `sudo kill` you are implicitly running `sudo /bin/kill`.